# D3 Bubble Chart (in CoffeeScript) Mouseover Changes Color of Bubbles of the Same Group

Tags: javascript, d3.js, coffeescript, data-visualization

I created a bubble chart with d3.js. Each fruit below has a bubble: the radius is defined by the count of the fruit, each bubble has a label with its name on it, and all bubbles have the same color. I've got them to work. Now I'm trying to do is that when I hover one bubble, other bubbles of the same group will change to the same color, say yellow; and when I unhover, the bubbles goes back to the original color.

data.csv

```
name,count,group
apple,5,red
grape,10,purple
banana,8,yellow
cherry,2,red
pineapple,1,yellow
...
```

And here is some relevant section of visual.coffee:

```
  rValue = (d) -> parseInt(d.count)
  idValue = (d) -> d.name
  textValue = (d) -> d.name
  groupValue = (d) -> d.group

  transformData = (rawData) ->
    rawData.forEach (d) ->
      d.count = parseInt(d.count)
      # rawData.sort((a, b) -> return -(a.value - b.value))
      # rawData.sort((a, b) -> return -(a.value - b.value))
      rawData.sort(() -> 0.5 - Math.random())
      # rawData.sort (a, b) -> b.value - a.value
    rawData

  chart = (selection) ->
    selection.each (rawData) ->

      data = transformData(rawData)
      maxDomainValue = d3.max(data, (d) -> rValue(d))
      rScale.domain([0, maxDomainValue])

      svg = d3.select(this).selectAll("svg").data([data])
      svgEnter = svg.enter().append("svg")
      svg.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right )
      svg.attr("height", height + margin.bottom )

      node = svgEnter.append("g").attr("id", "bubble-nodes")
        .attr("transform", "translate(#{margin.left},#{margin.top})")

      node.append("rect")
        .attr("id", "bubble-background")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .on("click", clear)

      label = d3.select(this).selectAll("#bubble-labels").data([data])
        .enter()
        .append("div")
        .attr("id", "bubble-labels")

      update()

      # see if url includes an id already
      hashchange()

      # automatically call hashchange when the url has changed
      d3.select(window)
        .on("hashchange", hashchange)


  update = () ->
    data.forEach (d,i) ->
      d.forceR = Math.max(minCollisionRadius, rScale(rValue(d)))

    force.nodes(data).start()

    updateNodes()
    updateLabels()

  connectEvents = (d) ->
    d.on("click", click)
    d.on("mouseover", mouseover)
    d.on("mouseout", mouseout)

  clear = () ->
    location.replace("#")

  click = (d) ->
    location.replace("#" + encodeURIComponent(idValue(d)))
    d3.event.preventDefault()

  hashchange = () ->
    id = decodeURIComponent(location.hash.substring(1)).trim()
    updateActive(id)

  updateActive = (id) ->
    node.classed("bubble-selected", (d) -> id == idValue(d))
    # if no node is selected, id will be empty
    if id.length > 0
      d3.select("#status").html("<h3>The word <a href=\"http://www.google.com\"><span class=\"active\">#{id}</span></a> is now active</h3>")
    else
      d3.select("#status").html("<h3>No word is active</h3>")


  mouseover = (d) ->
    node.classed("bubble-hover", (p) -> p == d)
    node.classed("same-group",(d) -> group == groupValue(d))

  mouseout = (d) ->
    node.classed("bubble-hover", false)

  chart.jitter = (_) ->
    if !arguments.length
      return jitter
    jitter = _
    force.start()
    chart

  chart.height = (_) ->
    if !arguments.length
      return height
    height = _
    chart

  chart.width = (_) ->
    if !arguments.length
      return width
    width = _
    chart

  chart.r = (_) ->
    if !arguments.length
      return rValue
    rValue = _
    chart

  return chart

root.plotData = (selector, data, plot) ->
  d3.select(selector)
    .datum(data)
    .call(plot)
```

Specifically, I wrote the following to achieve hover to change color in the same group and also added the corresponding CSS code, but it isn't changing color of the bubbles of the same group.

```
  mouseover = (d) ->
    node.classed("bubble-hover", (p) -> p == d)
    node.classed("same-group",(d) -> group == groupValue(d))
```

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: You don't seem to have `group` defined anywhere. I'm also not sure why you have two classes for this. Should probably be something like `node.classed("bubble-hover", (p) -> groupValue(p) == groupValue(d))`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Didn't I define it in `groupValue = (d) -> d.group`, since every data point has `name`, `count` & `group`? If not, how should I define it? Please advise. As for why I wrote it in two lines, I wanted to differentiate between the one being hovered on and the ones belonging to the same group by giving them separate classes.

Comment: I mean `group` in the mouseover handler. And in that case your code should be `d3.select(this).classed("bubble-hover", true)` and `node.classed("same-group", (p) -> groupValue(p) == groupValue(d))`.